# expected insurance value of the person

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, actuarial-science

A person has a 0.16% chance of dying in the next year. A life insurance policy with a \$50,000 death benefit costs him \$125. What is the expected value of the insurance for the person?

a) -$45

b) $45

c) -$117

d) $117

It should be $105 ((1-0.16)*125) but its not in the option.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: $.16\%$ is $.0016$

Comment: Where did your formula come from?  In particular, where did $105$ come from?  If nothing else, you appear to be ignoring the potential payout.

Comment: For the next year the expected benefit is $0.16\% \cdot \$ 50,000$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @lulu the surviving chance is 0.84% (1 - 0.16%(chance of dying)). so i thought the expected amount should be the surviving chance * insurance cost which came out to be $105 (0.85% of \$125).

Comment: Ah.  Usually the notation $A(B\times C)$ , with $A,B,C$ real numbers, means $A\times B\times C$.  What you wrote is very confusing.  In any case, you are forgetting that the fellow must be the $\$125$ in all cases (no probability attached to that) but the payout is only realized with probability $.0016$

Comment: A side note: The death itsself  and its (financial) consequences has not be regarded in this calculation. A very simple view of life.

Comment: got it thanks @lulu

Answer (score 0):

If the payout on death is $\$50000$ and the probability of dying is $0.16\%=0.0016$, then the present value of the death benefit is $\$80$. But the insured has to pay $\$125$, thus the net value of the insurance is $-\$45$, which is answer a.